# How to define a new command that is a wrapper of an existing command and accepts all original flags?

Tags: command, cd-command

What I want to do is to make a command that prints some related info if the command is successful. As an example, if I define an alias as

```
alias cd='cd /path/to/destination/  &&  echo "changing directory to echo $(pwd)"'
```

Then when I execute `cd`, the terminal will print `changing directory to /path/to/destination/`. But with this solution, I cannot use flags defined for the command `cd`. I want to define a command that behaves like above but also accepts all flags originally defined for the underlying command. I plan to do this for `mkdir`, `cp`, and `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it as a script or a function in `~/.bash_profile`:

Script, e.g. `mycmd.sh`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

your "$1"
commands "$1"
shift
the_original_command "$@"
```

Function:

```bsh
mycmd() {
    your "$1"
    commands "$1"
    shift
    the_original_command "$@"
}
```

If you need to use more than one argument, e.g.

```
your "$1"
commands "$2"
```

use `shift 2`, 3, 4, 5, etc.

So, it's gonna be:

```
your "$1"
commands "$2"
shift 2
the_original_command "$@"
```

Comment: In the context of my example, where does the `echo` command go? And I don't get what `your "$1"   commands "$1"` means. If there is only one argument why I would need two lines here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following commands to your Bash configuration file (`~/.bashrc`), and then restart the shell.

```
function cd_echo() {
    cd "${@}";
    echo "Changing directory to $(pwd)";
}

alias cd="cd_echo";
```

Test Result:

```
$ cd /home
Changing directory to /home

$ cd -P /dev
Changing directory to /dev
```

Comment: It looks like I cannot use flags defined for `cd` with the new `cd`.

Comment: I changed the variable ```${1}``` to ```${@}```. Now ```cd``` can accept flags.